# Android Studio Launcher Icon - Icon Name Must Be Set

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-icons

I am developing a Flutter app right now and trying to change the Android app's icon to a .png image. On Android Studio, I get this error when I do File -> New -> Image Asset:

[image: Icon Must Be Set Error]

Any help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you `pubspec.yaml` file add this,

```
dev_dependencies: 
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.6.1"

flutter_icons:
  android: true 
  ios: "Example-Icon"
  image_path: "assets/icon/icon.png"
  image_path_android: "assets/icon/icon_android.png"
  image_path_ios: "assets/icon/icon_ios.png"
  adaptive_icon_background: "#FFFAFAFA"
  adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/icon/icon-foreground.png"
```

More information can be found [here](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons)